# How to add list values in python

Tags: python

I am stuck with scenario , where i want to add values of list

For example :

```
my_list=[2,4,5,8]
```

**My Output :**

```
[2,6,11,19]
```

It should add like 2 , next value `4+2 : 6 , 6+5 : 11 , 8+11 : 19`

How to read previous values ? and add with next value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.cumsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) like below:

```
a=[2,4,5,8]

np.cumsum(a)
# array([ 2,  6, 11, 19])

np.cumsum(a).tolist()
# [ 2,  6, 11, 19]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact process that [itertools.accumulate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) does.

> Make an iterator that returns accumulated sums

```
from itertools import accumulate

my_list = [2,4,5,8]
my_list_accumulated = list(accumulate(my_list))
print(my_list_accumulated)
```

Output:

```
[2, 6, 11, 19]
```

Comment: I love numpy, but this should be the accepted answer ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
my_list=[2,4,5,8]
new_list = []
if(len(my_list)>0):
    new_list = my_list[0]
    for i in range(1,len(my_list)):
        new_list.append(my_list[i-1]+my_list[i])
```

`new_list` will contain the result

Answer (score 0):

I hope its readable and usefull

```
my_list = [2, 4, 5, 8]

for index in range(len(my_list)-1):
    if index != 0:
       my_list[index] += my_list[index - 1]


[2, 6, 11, 19]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).